# How to know when user closes program executed with exec() in Java

Tags: java, process, exec

I'm launching VLC in Java using exec():

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/vlc -");
```

How can I know when the VLC window is closed?
I know exitValue() returns the exit value of the process. And if the process hasn't finished yet, it returns IllegalThreadStateException.
So I guess I could have a while loop with a try/catch to keep checking if exitValue() throws an exception, and when it doesn't, it means that the process has finished. But that seems like a waste of CPU time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `waitFor()` method of your `Process` object (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--)

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/vlc -");
int exitCode;
try {
   exitCode = process.waitFor();
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
}
```

This will make your current thread wait for the termination of the process (without busy waiting = CPU friendly), or until it is interrupted.

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is, I don't want to stop the current thread.

Comment: Sorry, but your question implied that this is what you wanted. Your example of a while loop would have done it too. As noted in another comment, you can always start another thread to do the job. If you have a more specific requirement, you will have to change your question accordingly.

Comment: Problem solved with waitFor(). I launched VLC in the main thread and started a new thread with the waitFor() in it, followed by the code I want to execute when VLC closes. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Process.waitFor() to wait until the executed process is finished.

See:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29

Comment: But doesn't waitFor() stop the current thread until the process has finished? I don't want to block the thread

Comment: You have to start your process in a separate thread. When this new thread is terminating (e.g. end of the run() - method) it can throw an event to the main thread informing it that this process is finished.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.